# Is there a shorter way to represent a time in milliseconds?

Tags: java

I am asked to store the time right before my algorithm start, and time when it ends, and also need to provide the difference between them (end time - start time).

But the `System.currentTimeMillis()` function generates values that are too long:

```
start=1497574732045
  end=1497574732168
```

Is there a way to make this value just 3 digits like "123" but also be as precise as using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` function?

Comment: **Why** are you concerned about the number of digits **and** no, consider any time +- 500ms.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch - The difference between `start` and `end` will be the amount of milliseconds which passed between those two points. You should start by subtracting `end` from `start`, you can then format the value as seconds if you wish from there (although you're likely to end up with `0s`)

Comment: You mean like `% 1000` ?

Comment: are you asking about storing the long values (like in a database) or just printing (end time - start time)?

Comment: If you go back in time to January 1, 1970 and perform your sample then, you'll get the results you're looking for... provided your end time doesn't exceed your start time by more than 1 second.  Then, I'm pretty sure you'll need more than 3 digits for the precision.

Comment: @phatfingers new DeLoreanDate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the start and end times separately, there are only two ways (I can think of) to make the values smaller.

Firstly, `System.currentTimeMillis()` counts from January 1, 1970 UTC. But if your clock is never going to run previous to "now", you can subtract a fixed amount of time. I chose 1497580000000 as it's definitely in the past at the time I wrote this and its a nice even number.

Second, divide the value by any amount of precision you are willing to lose. In your case you might not want to even do that, but here I chose 100.

The numbers returned look small now, but they will continue to get bigger as the difference between the current time and 1497580000000 become more pronounced.

The preferred solution is to not do any of this at all, but just store the long value if you can.

You'll never magic a large precise number into only 3 decimal digits. Not without quantum mechanics.

```
{
    long start = 1497584001010L;
    long end =   1497584008000L;

    System.out.println("Diff: " + (end - start));

    int compactStart = compact(start);
    int compactEnd = compact(end);

    System.out.println("Compact Start: " + compactStart);
    System.out.println("Compact End:   " + compactEnd);

    System.out.println("Diff: " + (expand(compactEnd) - expand(compactStart)));

}

private int compact(long millis) {
    return (int)((millis - 1497580000000L)/100);
}

private long expand(int millis) {
    return (millis + 1497584000000L)*100;
}
```

Result...

```
Diff: 6990
Compact Start: 40010
Compact End:   40080
Diff: 7000
```

Note 7000 doesn't equal 6990 because of the intentional precision loss.

Answer (score 2):

as the currentTimeMillis() description says:-

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.
>
> Returns:
>   the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

in your case use this simple trick and you will get the desired result.

```
    Long startTime= Long.parseLong("1497674732168");
    Long endTime= Long.parseLong("1497574732168");
    System.out.println("start time is"+new Date(startTime)+"end time is"+new Date(endTime));
```